# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hdfs

I am new to apache hadoop. I am installing the multi-node cluster but I am getting two errors. I am not aware about what kind of errors these are and why they have generated.I have googled alot about the errors but I was not able to find out the reason behind the error generation.

```
  Error:Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName

  Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode
```

Both the errors are generated due to the datanode or slaves. I need to know about the kind of errors, the reason for generation,and how to resolve them. Thank you.

Comment: Which version of hadoop are you using? When do you get this error?

Comment: version : hadoop-1.2.1

Comment: error happens when i execute the command : bin/start-dfs.sh

Answer (score 2):

> Error:Could not find or load main class
>   **org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName**
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   **org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode**

These errors occur if Hadoop cannot find `hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar` file in its classpath.

To rectify this error, you need to add this file in Hadoop classpath.

**1.** Copy `hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar` to $HADOOP_HOME/lib folder

**2.** Add the following line in `hadoop-env.sh`:

`export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar`

> **NOTE:** **$HADOOP_HOME** should point to hadoop installation folder.

**OPTIONAL:** If you want to avoid other "`Could not find or load main class`" error in future, just do this instead of step 2.

`export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/*.jar`

Answer (score 2):

Change folder which stores:
    hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir

For example:

```
sudo mkdir hb
chown hduser:hadoop /home/hduser/hb
```

And in hbase-site.xml change this property

```
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/home/hduser/hb/zookeeper</value>
</property>
```