# Hmaster is not starting hbase 1.1.2 with hadoop 2.7.1

Tags: hadoop, logging, hbase, bigdata

I have `hadoop 2.7.1` installed and it's running successfully.
I tried to install `hbase 1.1.2` by referring this link:

https://archanaschangale.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/installing-pseudo-distributed-hbase-on-ubuntu/

Configuration :
 `hbase-env.sh`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
export HBASE_REGIONSERVERS=/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-1.1.2/conf/regionservers
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

hbase-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
    </property>

    <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
    </property>

    <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
    </property>

    <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
    </property>

    <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/hduser/hbase/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

And

```
bashrc
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-1.1.2
export PATH=$PATH:$HBASE_HOME/bin
```

But when I tries to start hbase using
    bin/start-hbase.sh

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool
starting master, logging to /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/logs/hbase-hduser-master-master-VirtualBox.out
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.RFA
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "RFA".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.RFAS
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "RFAS".
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.VersionInfo).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the folder which stores

```
hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir
```

This is link for the stack overflow answer:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635648/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-apache-hadoop-hdfs-server-datanode/33737675#33737675)